# Why does _ match 0?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Hey i've seen the following function declaration

```
half :: Int -> Int
half (x+2) = 1 + (half x)
half _ = 0
```

Why is the last line matching a zero respectively why does that function work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer the title question: `_` matches *anything*.

> Prelude> case 0 of _ -> "match"
>   "match"
>   Prelude> case True of _ -> "match"
>   "match"
>   Prelude> case "Eeeek" of _ -> "match"
>   "match"
>   Prelude> case undefined of _ -> "match"
>   "match"

That doesn't really seem to be your question though; in your example `_` doesn't *match* `0`, but *maps to* `0`. So the answer to "why" is basically "because it was defined this way". As to why this makes for a useful function: again the `_` pattern matches anything – anything *that doesn't already match one of the previous patterns*. Now, in your case the previous pattern happens to be a pesky [`n+k`-pattern, which isn't actually legal in modern Haskell](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK). The standard alternative is, I think, indeed more explainative:

```
half x | x>=2  = 1 + half (x - 2)
half _ = 0
```

so, if we pretend the signature was

```
half :: Nat -> Nat
```

then the second clause is basically just

```
half 1 = 0
half 0 = 0
```

which makes rather obvious sense for integer division.

What's perhaps not quite so obvious is why the *first* clause works. But you can grasp it quite easily by picturing `x` as a "resource" that's consumed recursively: you keep taking away two units from it, and each time add one to the result. In the end, the result will thus be half of `x`' original value.

Comment: thank you. didnt know about this side condition of n>=0 in the (somewhat weird) n+k pattern

Answer (score 1):

It matches because the pattern to match is simply a "variable", so it will match any value.

Say you have this function:

```
fun :: Int -> String
fun 1 = "one"
fun 2 = "two"
fun x = "other"
```

Since the last pattern is a variable, it will match any number that is *not* `1` or `2`. But note that we don't actually *use* `x` in the last pattern; we simply use it to match any number. What if we don't want to have to come up with names for variables that we won't even use? The answer to that is the underscore (`_`). We can simply replace the `x` in the last match with `_`:

```
fun _ = "other"
```